# Javascript Countdown Timer Repeat and execute php code

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have javascript countdown timer from 30 -> 0.

```
var count = 30;

var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
  count = count - 1;
  if (count <= 0) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    return;
  }

  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count;
}
```

and html :

```
<span id="timer">30</span>
```

I want the countdown to repeat automatically when it is over (after 30 secs) and  execute php code (Select and show data from mysql)

Comment: at the end of your timer .. do an `AJAX` request to a seperated `php` file ..

Comment: I imagine that you are well aware that your code does not produce a real wait of 30 seconds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your countdown .. Check for `if (count <= 0)`  -- If it does, run your `AJAX` call to a file -- say --- **file.php** which contains your `php` and `sql`. Also in the `if` you are going to reset your counter back to 30.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<span id="timer">30</span>
<div id="#ajax-results"></div>

<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    var count=30;

    var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);

    function timer()
    {
        count=count-1;
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            count=30;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'file.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'somevariable=whatever',
                success: function(data) {
                    //called when successful
                    $('#ajax-results').html(data);
                }
            });
        }

        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count;

    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```